# Using Poetry (with virtual environments?)

Tags: python-poetry, virtual-environment

First a bit of background. I use anaconda. I have been using it for years and got used to it.
Not being used to use "virtual environments" (I get confused by the names, venv, pyenv, etc)

I have been recommended (and my workplace is going to adopt) to use Poetry. So I have read the basics.

However I read in one tutorial that it is "recommended to install Poetry inside a virtual environment"

Wait a minute! I thought Poetry will create a virtual environment...

Anyway, right now (being used to I know...) I have installed Poetry inside a conda environment.

But I want to ask what is the proper way to install and use Poetry.

- Should I install it over the machine?
- Should I install it on a virtual environment? If yes which and how?
- Does Poetry create virtual environments?

I have also installed pyenv and I keep confusing it with venv....(or was it virtualenv??)

Comment: Have you seen [poetry's installation docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation) yet? The first paragraph covers why using a dedicated virtual environment is needed. Each installation method also includes a blurb on how it isolates poetry in a virtual environment

Comment: TL;DR: poetry is itself a Python program, which has dependencies. _Those_ dependencies should be installed inside a virtual environment so that you don't accidentally break poetry by messing which versions of those dependencies are installed. Manually installing poetry into a virtual environment you created is considered advanced usage. The recommended installation methods (pipx and the official installer) both use a _self-managed_ virtual environment behind the scenes, which you never directly interact with in normal usage.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to install Poetry via `pipx`:

```
pipx install poetry
```

This way `poetry` is accessible to the current user without activating any virtual environment.

Yes, `poetry` creates virtual environments and manages the dependencies (among other features).

`pyenv` is a tool to install different Python versions in the same system. `venv` creates virtual environments and, like `poetry`, may use any Python version previously installed by `pyenv`.